# How to introduce \n if a number ends with capital letter?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, substitution

I was wondering how to introduce `\n` in number that ends with *any* capital letter.

Input:

```
-0.2388232559C,0,6.3332912323,-0.7423880855,0.5325197794H,0,7.5055174791
```

Desired output:

```
-0.2388232559
C,0,6.3332912323,-0.7423880855,0.5325197794
H,0,7.5055174791
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed's `s` command can work with `\n`, so you can just use `sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\n\1/g'`.

Comment: That makes just a newline before every capital letter, the asker wants a newline after a **number** that ends with a capital letter.

Comment: @chaos right for generic input but where do you see any capital letter alone in the representative provided sample

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Not in the sample, but the first sentence of the question states it.

Comment: sample is used, if not, there is also no behaviour about *where* to put the \n and what about `1A2B`. So, or the question is adapted to clarify the case, or the reply is compliant. Now, your comment is constructive by making an assumption that there is no letter alone data

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
input="-0.2388232559C,0,6.3332912323,-0.7423880855,0.5325197794H,0,7.5055174791"
echo "$input" | sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([A-Z]\),/\1\n\2,/g'
```

The sed part does the following:

It searches for a digit `[0-9]`, followed by a capital letter `[A-Z]` followed by a comma `,` and replaces it with the found digit `\1` and the desired newline `\n`

Comment: you need to also use a group for the letter itself, or you loose it `\([A-Z]\)/\1\n\2`